# JLanguage getFirstDay()

Tags: joomla-3.x

Can anyone help me understand why JLanguage->getFirstDay() returns 0 (Sunday) for EN-GB, and 1 (Monday) for EN-US?

The UNICODE CLDR has 1 for EN-GB, and 0 for EN-US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getFirstDay()` returns `$this->metadata['firstDay']` and defaults to `0` if it doesn't exist.

The `$metadata` variable contains an array of data which is pulled from the following file:

> joomla\language\en-GB\en-GB.xml

I'm not too sure why, but when installing a language pack in the back-end Language Manager, it doesn't add the new XML file, just the `.ini` files.

So at a guess, you could try duplicating the file mentioned above, rename it to `en-US.xml`, open the file and change the `<firstDay>0</firstDay>` to whatever your preferred value is.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm porting our calendar plugin to Joomla, and one of the things you have to know to draw a calendar is what the first day of the week is. For a commercial product, having the user tinker with files is just a non-starter. I guess this means that I have to put my own configuration widget in place to let users override this.